# Nuget altering existing lines in web,.config

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to find out how to alter existing lines in a web.config via NuGet installer,
I can find out how to insert lines that don't already exist, but not how to alter existing lines.

Does anyone know where the references are on your to do it?

Comment: We want to modify the ELMAH lines to use the assembly ", JcdcHelper.Elmah", instead of ",Elmah", we modified elmah to give us app specific information as well as the default.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the PowerShell xml functionality.  It's *incredibly* powerful.

For instance, if you want to add a setting to the web.config:

```
$webConfigXml = [xml](Get-Content .\Web.config);
$addNode = $webConfigXml.CreateElement('add');
$addNode.SetAttribute("key", "SomeKey");
$addNode.SetAttribute("value", "SomeValue");
$webConfigXml.configuration.appsettings.AppendChild($addNode);
set-content web.config $webConfigXml.OuterXml;
```

The only downside is that your xml will no longer be pretty printed.  But that can be easily fixed as well: [Xml Pretty Print in PowerShell](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2006/08/08/xml-pretty-print-in-powershell/).  Alternatively, plain old file editing isn't too difficult either.

Comment: Not what i was after but cool so I'll give you abump bot not an answer.